# Sending a "larger" collection of data to an Azure WCF Service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, azure, wcf

I'm trying to create a web service using Azure.

For the time being, everything is being run locally. The web service and Azure work fine, a simple `string Test()` method which returns "Hello world" works without problems, as you'd expect. ;)

Now, I've created two methods which add rows to Azure Data Tables. The first sends (using a special `DataContract`) a single row of data, and this works fine.

The second is for sending larger amount of data, and sends an `IEnumerable`. So, to test the service, I've created a client application which creates a number of random data to send. If I create up to 42 rows and send that, all goes well.

Above that, I get a `400 Bad request` error.

The problem is that there's no inner message to work with (or rather, that WAS the inner message). I strongly suspect it has to do with the size of the request however.

Note, that if I put a breakpoint on the service's method, it doesn't even get that far. I've read quite a few various forum posts regarding similar issues, but those seemed to deal with ordinary WCF services, not Azure ones, and so the `Web.config` file doesn't contain definitions for bindings nor endpoints, which would be something I could work with.

Please help.

PS. I realise I may have posted very little information. If something else is needed, please ask, and I'll do my best to include it.

Comment: Are you working on the Dev Fabric?

Comment: Aye, I am. (Damn character limit >.<)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following lines to the `Web.config` file (under `system.serviceModel`) in the Azure service project (**NOT** the `Web.config` in the client application) resolved the issue:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <!--The basicHttpBinding is used for clients which use the generated code to transmit data; the following
  settings make it possible to send larger amounts to the service-->
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000" receiveTimeout="01:00:00">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10000000" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```